# Scoring history with noise in h2o deep learning

Tags: python, deep-learning, h2o, scoring

I use h2o Deep Learning with Python. My problem is a time series forecasting problem as I want to predict the evolution of the number of sunspots. Here are all the values of sunspots since 1749 : http://www.sidc.be/silso/DATA/SN_ms_tot_V2.0.txt.

I want to use a sliding window of 43 months hence my dataset is now composed of 44 columns and 3170 rows (the value I want to predict is the 44th, based on the 43rd previous month).

My data looks like that :

*135.90, 137.90, 140.20, 143.80, 146.40 ... 68.10, 63.60, 60.40*

*137.90, 140.20, 143.80, 146.40, 147.90, ... 63.60, 60.40, 61.10*

*140.20, 143.80, 146.40, 147.90, 148.40, ... 60.40, 61.10, 59.70*

*...*

*99.0, 104.6, 107.0, 106.9, 107.6, ... 27.80, 26.50, 25.70*

I have divided my data set into training (first 80% rows) and validation (last 20%). See my code below :

```
import h2o
from h2o.estimators.deeplearning import H2ODeepLearningEstimator

h2o.init()

test=h2o.import_file("validationSet_43month.txt")
train=h2o.import_file("trainingSet_43month.txt")
l=train.shape[1] 
x=train.names[0:l-1] 
y=train.names[l-1]

Factiv="Tanh"
HiddenLayer=[100,100]
Nepochs=2000

model=H2ODeepLearningEstimator(
    activation=Factiv,
    hidden=HiddenLayer,
    epochs=Nepochs,
    reproducible=True,
    stopping_rounds=0, #I want to see an eventual overfitting on scoring history
    seed=123456789)
model.train(x=x,y=y,training_frame=train,validation_frame=test)
```

I want to draw the scoring history in order to know the optimum number of epochs to use but my scoring history seems to have a lot of **noise, with peaks** (see pictures).
[Scoring history on 10,000 epochs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yXcKp.png)

[zoom on 2,000 epochs for validation deviance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8BSRQ.png)

I thought I would get this type of scoring history instead : 
[Normal scoring history](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rQaNy.jpg)

- 1) I tried to use Tanh instead of Rectifier with [8] hidden neurons but the noise is still here so it is probably not due to numerical instability.

[Scoring history 43-8-1 ; Activation=Tanh ; epochs=2600](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SNmYK.png)

- 2) Then I tried to add some hidden neurons ([100,100]) and still use Tanh. I still have a lot of noise :

[Scoring history 43-100-100-1 Tanh](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4gV1t.png)

- 3) I tried to use Random forest and Gradient boosting with default parameters, scoring_history looks good :

[Scoring history Random forest](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PX0Gy.png)

[Scoring history GBM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BRJ9X.png)

**Does anybody have an explanation for the look of my scoring history ?**

Comment: It'd be good to show a fully reproducible example of what you are doing (is the data public?). I still think the most interesting part of your question is that the [100,100] network is getting a much higher deviance than all the other models. It smells more like it was given the wrong training data, or something else was different, just when making that model. (BTW, your main question, about the noise in your 2-neuron scoring history I would still dismiss as due to using too few neurons.)

Comment: @Darren Cook thank you for you answers. You were right, I did a mistake when trying to plot scoring history for 100-100 Tanh model. However, the graph is still Noisy (I updated the picture in my post). My data is public but I reorganized it as I explain in my post. I am new to StackOverflow, I can't upload a file to give you my data set, can I ?

Answer (score 0):

The learning is narrowing in on the best set of weights, and sometimes overshoots. Though, as you say, your chart is quite noisy.

When you say your network is 43-8-1, do you mean you gave `hidden` as [43,8,1], or you gave hidden as [8] ?

If the former, remember that H2O tries to be helpful, so the output layer (1 neuron as you are doing a regression) and input layer (43 neurons, if all data is numeric, otherwise more) are created for you.

If the latter, `[2]` and `[8]` are very low numbers, possibly too few (and too few layers) for it to be effective (depending on your data of course).

Whether the former, or the latter, did you try more neurons? E.g. the default of `[200,200]`? It will obviously take more time to do each epoch, but is the scoring history smoother now?

I can imagine how only having a few neurons can make the training score get quite jumpy.

But if that isn't it, I've seen noisy scoring history charts when hitting numeric instability. So you could try switching from Rectifier to Tanh.

More generally, it is worth building the all-defaults model first, as a baseline to compare to; in particular I'd avoid touching rho, learning rate, momentum, etc. H2O does a good job of choosing defaults for them.

Comment: Yes 43 and 1 are the number of neurons on input and output layers given by default by h2o. [2] and [8] are my hidden neurons. I have tried [30,20] with rectifier and [8] with tanh. I am going to try more hidden neurons with Tanh

Comment: @T.RB Your 100-100-tanh chart looks like it is not learning anything. Personally, my next step would be to try a random forest and GBM on the same data (using all default settings), and see if they are bad too. If so, maybe the problem is a lack of signal in the data?

Comment: I tried random forest and GBM with defaults parameters, scoring history is smoother (see my post updated).